# Are Caltrops and Chakram Double viable on Nightmare?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been using CT with slowing enemies for the extra damage with Chakram and I made a massacre out of Normal! Dodging with Vault while laying CT and then spamming Chakram.

Will this tactis also work on Nightmare difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

For early nightmare i've tried it out and it works pretty darn well